# Use of "using namespace" when declaring that namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, coding-style

Suppose I have the following files:

```
// SomeClass.h
namespace Example
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        ...
        SomeClass someFunction();
        ...
    };

}

// SomeClass.cpp
Example::SomeClass Example::SomeClass::SomeFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

Would there be any consequences to add "using namespace Example;" before the namespace in SomeClass.h to eliminate the need of adding the "Example::" scope operator to things in the Someclass.cpp file? Even if there are no conesequences, would this be considered bad coding practice?

The change would be as follows:

```
// SomeClass.h
using namespace Example;

namespace Example
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        ...
        SomeClass someFunction();
        ...
    };

}

// SomeClass.cpp
SomeClass SomeClass::SomeFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I use that all the time in .cpp files. I haven't seen any downsides yet. However, I haven't used them in .h files. Keep in mind that you can't use `using namesapce Example;` before the namespace is introduced.

Comment: Didn't consider throwing that in the .cpp, thanks.

Comment: As R Sahu said, do not throw a `using namespace` in your header.  It pollutes the global namespace of every file which includes it (not fun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, please don't put `using namespace ...;` in the global area. You can just do this:

**SomeClass.h**

```
// using namespace Example; // never here please

namespace Example
{
    using namespace OtherExample; // this is okay (not global)

    class SomeClass
    {
        ...
        SomeClass someFunction();
        ...
    };

}
```

**SomeClass.cpp**

```
namespace Example // same as in .h
{
    using namespace OtherExample; // this is okay (not global)

    SomeClass SomeClass::SomeFunction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I would also suggest with potentially huge namespaces like `std::` to *never* use `using namespace std;` even within your own namespaces because they simply drag in too many common symbol names.